# Pass special characters in value input checkbox

Tags: php

I need to pass special characters within the value of a checkbox field.

The special characters are :

```
Pi&ugrave; 
m<sup>2</sup>
```

which are equivalent to word

```
Più
m raised to 2
```

I did this, but I do not know if it's correct :

```
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input pradio" name="p8" id="p8_1" 
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($stringadomanda8, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?> 
di 60m<?php echo htmlspecialchars($iniziometroquadro)?>2<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($finemetroquadro, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>">
```

the file that expects the value so

```
    $p8 = [
    'Pi&ugrave; di 60m<sup>2</sup>' => 1.00,
    'Da 51 a 60m<sup>2</sup>' => 0.95,
    'Da 41 a 50m<sup>2</sup>' => 0.90,
    'Fino a 40m<sup>2</sup>' => 0.85,
    'Piscina prefabbricata fino a 40m<sup>2</sup>' => 0.77,
];
```

I would like to make sure that the value with special characters is taken correctly.

If I try to print `echo htmlspecialchars($stringadomanda8, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` I get `Pi&ugrave;` but not `Più`.

Comment: value of checkbox is fixed? if fixed, then no need to pass value like that, you can just pass 1 or 0 from checkbox, then use IF/E:SE check in php and put special character value... JUST SUGGESTION

Comment: Why dont you use a select instead of an input for this? You could load the options for a select out of the array $p8 and compare the id when sending the data.

Comment: no, it's not fixed. Each checkbox has a different value.

Comment: Cool story. Was there a question? Looks more like a post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok are u getting any error with thsi example or just need to know better solution?

Comment: _“I need to pass special characters”_ - you don’t technically _need_ to; you could as well just use the numeric index position of the entry in your `$p8` array (either by reorganizing that into a `[ ['name' => 'Pi&ugrave; di 60m<sup>2</sup>', 'price' => 1.00], …]` form, or by counting the index at which a specific item is located some other way), and avoid any potential issues with “special characters” in the radio button value altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good to have those HTML elements as value of another HTML element but this is what you asked for:

```
// encode string with htmlentities() when you load the form
$txt = 'Più m<sup>2</sup>';
$encoded = htmlentities($txt);

// decode it with html_entity_decode() when you have received the value
echo html_entity_decode($encoded);
```